# Mounting S3 to DBFS(azure databricks), integer is adding with mount path

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have been mounted s3 bucket to DBFS.After unmounting i tried to list the files in the directory

eg : %fs ls /mnt/TmpS3SampleDB/

Output : java.io.FileNotFoundException: File/743456612344/mnt/TmpS3SampleDB/ does not exist.

In the above output , i don't understand where the interger-743456612344 is coming from.

Can anyone please explain . I am using azure databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Azure Databricks interact with object storage using directory and file semantics instead of storage URLs.

"743456612344" this is directory id associated with the Databricks.

When you try listing files in WASB using dbutils.fs.ls or the Hadoop API, you get the following exception:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File/ does not exist.

[image]

For more details, refer "[Databricks File System](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely generated by the Local API.

You should type

```
%fs ls /dbfs/mnt/TmpS3SampleDB/
```

Instead.

Comment: %fs ls /dbfs/mnt/TmpS3SampleDB/ - its just returning ok ?

Comment: It means the folder is empty, which makes sense since you unmounted it, right?